# Meaning of "Manifold of interest"

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, terminology, manifold-learning

While reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04381.pdf), I stumble upon the following sentence and couldn't figure out its meaning:

> Informally, for an input set of real images, **we say that the set of layer activations (for any layer L i ) forms a “manifold of interest”**. It has been long assumed that manifolds of interest in neural networks could be embedded in low-dimensional subspaces.

As far as I know, "manifold" in machine learning is the geometric representation of your data.

Comment: If you look at the dimensions of the activation tensor, and compare that to the activation tensors that actually occur for real images (that is, images from reality), I think they're saying that the latter don't "fill up" the space, the same way that real HxWxC images themselves make up only a tiny subset of all possible HxWxC tensors. The next sentence in the paper makes me think that the activations for a specific input set lie on the hypothetical manifold of all real activation tensors, rather than comprising a manifold themselves. A "manifold" here is essentially a smooth subset of space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: @Jason:  Can you please post that as an answer (that is, in the answers box, not just as a comment). It answers the Q. That way this does not linger on as unanswered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Real images (images from reality) with dimensions `(H, W, C)` make up only a tiny subset of all possible `(H, W, C)` tensors.

In the same way, the activation tensors resulting from real images in a neural network layer make up only a subset of all possible tensors of the same dimensions.

Subsets like these are what is meant by a "manifold" in ML research. To the best of my knowledge, they are not always proven to be smooth or locally Euclidean as in mathematics, but I don't think it hurts to imagine them that way.

Given a set of real images, those will result in a set of "real activation tensors", which will be members of ("lie on") that "real activation manifold", which is the manifold the authors are interested in.